# Create a CAShapeLayer around UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, cashapelayer

I have a **UIButton**, I want to create a BORDER outside its content.

I want to create it using **CAShapeLayer** or any other proper way.

How can I do so.

The property of **borderColor** and **BorderWidth** of **UIButton** creates a border inside the BUTTON. As more width, as more space is consumed from inside.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean outside? you cant create or add anyting away from the button frame. The border color /width are done within the frame,so there is no way to make it appear away from the frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is the *.m file
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()

// Comment A. Another label and button added to the class without adding them to the
// storyboard
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *firstButton;
 @end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.firstButton setTitle:@"Just a Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 40);
UIGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(theAction:)];
[self.firstButton addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

//The screen width and height
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

//The CALayer definition
CALayer *graphic = nil;
graphic = [CALayer layer];
graphic.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
graphic.position = CGPointMake(screenHeight/2, screenWidth/2);
graphic.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
graphic.opacity = 1.0f;
[graphic addSublayer:self.firstButton.layer];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:graphic];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)theAction:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"Button Tapped");
}
@end
```